# install dm-sqlite-adapter error on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ubuntu, datamapper

I'm installing data-mapper on ubuntu but I get an error while issuing the:
sudo gem install dm-sqlite-adapter

luc@nf310:~$ sudo gem install dm-sqlite-adapter

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dm-sqlite-adapter:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.2/ext/do_sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes... got it !!! I just had to issue a:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

before instlling the sqlite adapter.